# How can I move bone and mesh together?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, bones

Is there a way to move both the bones and mesh at the same time? And can I select only a certain number of vertices and bones? For example, I want to move them up slightly to match a real human male hand.[image]

Comment: If you mean you want to create a new rest pose, you can duplicate the Armature modifier, deactivate the copy, switch the armature to Pose mode and change the pose to the new one you want, select the mesh and apply the first Armature modifier, select the armature and in Pose mode go into the header menu > Pose > Apply > Appy Pose as Rest Pose. Activate the Armature modifier.

Comment: How do I duplicate armature modifier?

Comment: on the top right of the modifier, click on the down arrow and Duplicate

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want to do.

If you want to do this as part of an animation or a pose, then you should be in Pose mode. It looks like the proximal phalanx bones are connected to their palm parents, so you can't move them as is. You can however rotate up the parents, then counter-rotate down the child. If you don't want to deal with counter-rotating, you can check the option [Affect only parents](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/options.html#affect-only) in the sidebar.
Although this works, it's not ideal to be forced to do all that as relocating fingers is common during animation. Ideally the rig should allow to move the bones easily.One way to do this would be to simply set the proximal phalanx bones parents to disconnected. You can do this by selecting them in edit mode, then got to `Properties Editor` > `Bone` tab > `Relations` panel > maintain <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> pressed down and uncheck the `Connected` option.

If you want to do actually edit the rig and the mesh, then it's very different. Ideally you should validate your mesh before moving to rigging, especially the skinning phase. But in this case it should remain simple:

Start by removing the mesh object's "Armature Deform".
In object mode, select both the armature and the mesh object, and switch to edit mode. Then you should be able to select both the bones and vertices, and move them up as you wish. Don't hesitate to smoth the mesh a little bit, since moving things up might deform it in unwanted ways. You can also switch to sculpt mode to polish the result.
Once you are happy with the result, add back the Armature Deform modifier, don't forget to set its targets.